# Discord.js Bot [DISALLOWED_INTENTS]: Privileged intent provided is not enabled or whitelisted Error

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm having issues with Discord.js Bot on v13+. I'm getting `[DISALLOWED_INTENTS]` error. How can I fix this? Thanks.

```
(node:16060) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [DISALLOWED_INTENTS]: Privileged intent provided is not enabled or whitelisted. at WebSocketManager.createShards (C:\Users\schne\Desktop\Zeltux_v1.5.2\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:260:15)
[05:24:04] (node:16060) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. 
        
This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
        
[05:24:04] (node:16060) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: Its quite self-explanatory. " This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch()." 

Just use .catch() for catching the rejection.

Further info : 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: I'm sorry still new to coding. can you show me where the error is and a fix?
this is where the error is coming from.
https://pastebin.com/fH9xPg4D

Comment: Can you provide your bot's source code?

Comment: as its mentioned in error line 260 column 15.
\WebSocketManager.js:260:15)

Answer (score 39):

As the error suggests, `[DISALLOWED_INTENTS]: Privileged intent provided is not enabled or whitelisted`, you're probably using an intent that hasn't been enabled.

Gateway Intents were introduced to the library in v12 and allow you to pick which events your bot will receive. Intents are groups of pre-defined events that the discord.js client will conditionally subscribe to. For example, omitting the `DIRECT_MESSAGE_TYPING` intent would prevent the discord.js client from receiving any typing events from direct messages.

You'll have to go to [`Discord Developer Portal`](https://discord.com/developers/applications/), choose your application, go to the `Bot` section, and enable all the intents. (Or the ones you are using.)

[image: 2]